# Make public option for Saved searches

Tags: content-hub, dam

What permissions to add in the user group to have Make Public option for Saved searches?
I tried adding `M.SavedSearch` and `M.SavedSearchAccess` an Update and `CreatePublicLinks` permission but can't see this option. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To enable default saved searches, several steps need to be completed. Once you will complete all steps (1-15) given in this document, you can see all options.
The steps in this example include creating a new policy for the **Everyone** User group.

https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/33/content-hub/administration--adding-saved-search.html

Comment: I tried following the steps but I'm stuck in Step 3. In the Member security tab, M.SavedSearchAccess is not visible.

Comment: in 2nd steps did you try this Under the Rules tab, click on new rule button and search for the following two rules:

M.SavedSearchAccess (M.SavedSearchAccess)
Saved search (M.SavedSearch)

Comment: Yes, I added Rule for Saved search (M.SavedSearch), M.SavedSearchAccess (M.SavedSearchAccess) but in the Member security tab, M.SavedSearchAccess is not visible.

Comment: M.SavedSearch should default enable, but if anycase it is not then do manually through entity tab. https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/33/content-hub/content-user-manual--saved-search.html please go through this article, and use entity tab options.